# Multilevel Model or Simple Correlation Coefficients

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am interested in the relationship of several variables (questionnaire score = q1 (0-24); physiological measures = phys) across consecutive conditions (block = 4 consecutive conditions) and between experience groups (exp = 2 groups as a dummy variable). I have an overall sample size of N = 27 (12 = high exp., 15 = low exp), which all completed the 4 conditions.

My main interest now is whether a multilevel model is appropriate here to investigate whether the association between q1 and phys differs significantly across block and experiene groups.

The model would look something like this:

```
q1 ~ 1 + block * exp * phys + (1 | id)
```

Furthermore, I have several physiological measures. Does it make sense to incorporate them all in one model or should I rather go with a model that includes only one physiological predictor?

I am a little afraid that it would be easier to simply calculate the correlation coefficient for each subgroup at each block and compare those coefficients?

I am grateful for any sugggestions!

Comment: Why do you think a multilevel model is indicated ? How many times was each participant / id measured ? Do you have nested factors ? Splitting the data and analysing it in groups is generally a bad idea as it will result in lower statuistical power, and since you already have quite a small sample size, this would not be recommended.

Comment: Hi, each participant (n = 27) was measured 4 times (block) which icnluded the physiological measurement & a questionnaire. Furthermore, I have 2 groups (experienced (n=12) vs. unexperienced (n=15). So it is a repeated measures design.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, there are repeated measures within `id`, so fitting a mixed model with random intercepts for `id` would be a good idea.

Splitting the data into subgroups and comparing correlations is not a good idea, since it loses statistical power (since each test is on a smaller sample size) and you would also need to handle multiple testing issues.